# How to remove <br /> tags and more from a string?

Tags: php

I need to strip all `<br />` and all 'quotes' (`"`) and all 'ands' (`&`) and replace them with a space only ...

How can I do this? (in PHP)

I have tried this for the `<br />`:

```
   $description = preg_replace('<br />', '', $description);
```

But it returned `<>` in place of every `<br />`...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manipulate HTML it is generally a good idea to use a DOM aware tool instead of plain text manipulation tools (think for example what will happen if you enounter variants like  `<br/>`, `<br />` with more than one space, or even `<br>` or `<BR/>`, which altough illegal are sometimes used). See for example here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

Comment: Hmmm, seems to me that stripping might at least be a different case than other manipulations.  's what we have strip_tags() for.

Answer (score 10):

```
<?php

$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 7):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like this:

```
  str_replace("<br/>", " ", $orig );
```

preg_replace etc uses regular expressions and that may not be what you want.

Comment: Show us an example. This is a pretty straight forward function and it works fine for me. Maybe something else is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

If `str_replace()` isnt working for you, then something else must be wrong, because

```
$string = 'A string with <br/> & "double quotes".';
$string = str_replace(array('<br/>', '&', '"'), ' ', $string);
echo $string;
```

outputs

```
A string with      double quotes .
```

Please provide an example of your input string and what you expect it to look like after filtering.

Comment: Heh, perhaps he double quoted the original string.

Answer (score 4):

To remove all permutations of br:

```
<br> <br /> <br/> <br   >
```

check out the user contributed `strip_only()` function in

http://www.php.net/strip_tags

The "Use the DOM instead of replacing" caveat is always correct, but if the task is really limited to these three characters, this should be o.k.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$description = preg_replace('/<br \/>/iU', '', $description);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "Test<br>Test<br />Test<br/>";
$string = preg_replace( "/<br>|\n|<br( ?)\/>/", " ", $string );
echo $string;
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, to remove `<br/>` :

(`&gt;` is recognised whereas > isn't)

```
$temp2 = str_replace('&lt;','', $temp);

// echo ($temp2);

$temp2 = str_replace('/&gt;','', $temp2);

// echo ($temp2);

$temp2 = str_replace('br','', $temp2);

echo ($temp2);
```

Comment: &gt; instead of <   etc