# Escaping <br />

Tags: php, escaping

I'm trying to escape `<br />` and the likes in my Magento meta description.

So I've come up with this:

```
$characters = array("<br />", "<br>", "<br/>");
$badDesc = htmlspecialchars($this->getDescription());
$goodDesc = preg_replace($characters, ' ', $badDesc);
```

but the only characters thats escaped is "br /", but remaining is the "< >"

What do?

Comment: Similar question already answered

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778994/how-to-remove-br-tags-and-more-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is worth a shot (note: untested)

```
$desc = preg_replace('/\<br\b[^>]*>/i', ' ', $this->getDescription());
```

The expression explained:

- `\<br` is a literal match for the *string* `<br`
- `\b` is a *word boundary*: `preg_match('/foo\bbar/', 'foobar')` will not match, but `preg_match('/foo\bbar/', 'foo bar')` *will* match. That is, in essence a word-boundary. The beginning and ending of a word
- `[^>]*` matches *all* chareacters *except* for a literal `>`. The asterisk states that this *character class* may occur zero or more times: with `<br    />`, for example, this char class will match `/` (all spaces and the forward slash. Given this: `<br>`, then this part will be skipped (occurs zero times)
- `>` is a litteral match for the close-tag `>` char

If your markup is valid (ie not malformed), this expression will remove nothing you don't want to remove. But given strings like this: `<br data-string="<b>Don't include markup here</b>"/>` this expression will fail: there is a property that contains markup, but that is something I, personally, find revolting. You don't include markup in an attribute of a tag, IMO.
Another case where regex lets the guard down is when encountering malformed markup:

```
<br/The closing &gt; was omitted</p>
```

The regex will match the opening `<br`, then the `[^>]*` will match:

```
/The closing &gt; was omitted</p
```

Only to match the `>` of `</p>` as the end of the `br` tag. But that's just the *"fault"* of whoever wrote the markup...

Comment: This worked. But i don't really understand why, and if it could cause problems in removing other elements, that i really didnt want removed.

Comment: @AndersJytzler: I've explained the regex, but on the breaking/removing of some data. These are rare, highly unlikely cases. Even if you encounter them, that's just terrible practice, IMHO

Comment: @AndersJytzler: If this answer solved your problem, it would be nice to see it accepted

Comment: Yeah sure. Was playing around with the different answers. This one was the best imo.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little-known fact that `preg_*` functions can use matching brackets (parentheses, square, brace or angle) as delimiters. This is especially helpful as it means you don't have to escape those brackets inside the regex itself. Personally I like to use parentheses, as that helps me remember that "index 0" of the match array represents the entire match.

Anyway, in this case your angle brackets are being used as delimiters, making the expression search for `br /`, `br` and `br/`.

Use `str_replace` instead. You don't need `preg_*` for constant strings.

EDIT: That said, you're using `htmlspecialchars` first. In addition to using `str_replace`, make sure you are using the replacement *before* you mangle the HTML ;)

Comment: Actually, `preg_` will fit better since such things as `<br     />` (many spaces) could appear.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo But then again so could `<br style="clear:both;" />` and all its possible permutations. That is why we do NOT use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: Yes, yes. However, `/\<br[^\<\>]\/?\>/` is a simple solution. But parsing HTML with regex? No, it's a bad idea, I agree.

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo: Why `[^<]`? isn't `\b[^>]*` enough, as in my suggested sollution

Comment: Again, your regex fails on incorrectly-formed HTML such as `<br data-something="<b>Ohai there! I'm just breaking your regex!</b>" />` :p

Comment: @Kolink well, yes. And I'm not sure will this produce a line-break in browser or not (that is why accepting only valid markup). In any case, it's all problem-dependent (May be OP don't have such cases)

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo It would. Browsers use a parser, which understands what an attribute is and when it ends ^_^

Comment: If i use str_ instead of preg_, nothing at all happens. I don't understand what you mean by the last part of your answer

Comment: @AndersJytzler Nothing happens because you've *already* escaped them into `&lt;br&gt;` and similar. Remove the line breaks first, then escape any remaining HTML.

Comment: @kolink: Granted: malform markup is where regex's will _always_ fail, but for the OP's use, `DOMDocument` would be overkill. I've often advocated `DOMDocument`, even when others stated it was overkill, but in this case, parsing would really be too silly IMO

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp :

```
$desc = preg_replace('/\<br(\s.*)?\/?\>/i', " ", $this->getDescription());
```

Adapted from a [comment in the php docs](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.nl2br.php#86678).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are escaping a string to use as meta description, you should consider using `strip_tags` to remove all html tags.

```
$description = strip_tags($this->getDescription());
```

The function also takes a second argument

```
// strips every tag except <a> and <p>
$description = strip_tags($this->getDescription(), "<a><p>");
```